# How to convert str with microseconds completely to datetime.datetime

Tags: python-3.x, datetime

I'm trying to convert an str into datetime.datetime, and I want to do it with the microseconds intact. However the tutorials online don't show examples of carrying out the function with the microseconds, experimentations with the functions has turned out useless. Any help in solving this issue would be appreciated
Hope the code below helps

```
now = datetime.now()  # 2021-11-03 03:12:14.470747 this is with microseconds
now = str(now)  # convert to str
time = datetime.strptime(time, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")  # NameError here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your name error is due to a typo. `time` is undefined inside your parenthesis. Second your time format is not right (`/` instead of `-`and year at the wrong position):

```
time = datetime.strptime(now, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

Comment: The default str representation of a datetime object is ISO format, so you can easily parse it back to datetime with `fromisoformat` method of the datetime class